# how to select a portion of a data frame and convert it into an array in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame of shape (5,5) and I want to select the values from **columns** 1 through 3 and from that, i want to select **rows** 1 through 3 and convert them to an **array**.

for example, if this is the original dataFrame :

[image: Original DataFrame]

and i want to obtain the following as an array.

[image: desired array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like: `df.iloc[1:4,1:4].values` ?